# Display a certain category on a page - magento

Tags: php, magento

I would like to know how to show a certain gallery in magento, on a page.
I created a static block with name and identifier "category_listing" and put this code below:

`{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="366" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

Note that I want to show only the category 366.

And on the "mypage.phtml" I put this:

`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('category_listing')->toHtml(); ?>`

Now when I enter the page appear several categories, not just the category 366 (would be 3 products):

http://s24.postimg.org/q9o65red1/Captura_de_tela_2015_05_22_08_14.jpg

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
                  print $this->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock("blockname")
                 ->setTemplate("yourtemplate.phtml")
                 ->toHtml(); 
?>
```

and in your phtml file you define the function to get the product from a particular id

```php
<?php

    $categoryid = 366;

    $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->load($categoryid);
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>
       <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php  echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>
       </a>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: where do i put this first block?

Comment: where u want it to be displayed the block can be put in the html pages only.
For eg, if u put it under view.phtml it will render on all the product pages.
I am not sure where u want to put it .If u already have a block referring to mypag.html then call the block in this page.Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

you want to show only the category with id 366 but in your xml you defined the id 7?

-David

Comment: May you can check the loaded templates in your custom page. Use the template-hints feature of magneto. You find this under configuration->developer